# Змейка для C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, существует змейка в которой уже прописаны все надстройки (размер, отображение и т.д (ниже код))
Помогите изменить так - что бы можно было выбирать размер, фон, добавлять labelы, pictureBoxы поверх всего этого

Сам код [Pastebin.Com](http://pastebin.com/J1JptMYH)

Comment: Код лучше на какой-нибудь pastebin выложите... простыня это ужас, хорошо хоть не с планшета открыл)

В чём конкретно проблема? Судя по коду, длина и ширина задаются, фон тоже, что именно не получается сделать?

Comment: За код извиняюсь, сейчас загружу.
Нужно изменить код так - что бы можно было задавать все параметры в настройках (фоны, текстбоксы, лейблы)

Вот к примеру хочу дописать паузу, подключаю лейблы (при нажатии на P) что бы отображался текст "Пауза", с данным кодом я не могу этого сделать. Они просто не будут отображатся, или же изменяю размер в properties - ноль эмоций, даже если в саму Windows Form добавлю любую картинку - она не будет отображатся :(